# Java applet log in attempts counter not working properly

Tags: java, authentication, applet, counter

I am trying to make an applet for a site, and this log in applet it's what I started today to "play" with. It's in a project state, I have much more to work on it, but the log in attempts counter doesn't seem to be incremented as I want to, and I don't know why
(the `System.out.println(counter);` is there only for showing me that the counter remains 1), any thoughts?
    Also, can you point me into a direction(links, examples) of log in applets, a place where I could learn more and try to apply things for my own site? Thank you.
   Here is the code:

```
  import java.applet.Applet;
     import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/*   <applet code = "Login" width= 200 height = 200>
 </applet>
*/
public class Login extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
 Label lblUser, lblPassword;
 TextField txtUser, txtPassword;
 Button bLogin;
 boolean blnCorrect;

 public void init()
 {
  lblUser = new Label("UserName");
  add(lblUser);

  txtUser = new TextField(20);
  txtUser.setText("Username");
  add(txtUser);

  lblPassword = new Label("Password");
  add(lblPassword);

  txtPassword = new TextField(20);
  txtPassword.setText("Password");
  add(txtPassword);

  bLogin = new Button("Login");
  add(bLogin);
  bLogin.addActionListener(this);
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 { 




  if(txtUser.getText().equals("demo") && txtPassword.getText().equals("demopassword"))
   blnCorrect = true;
  else
   blnCorrect = false;



  repaint();
 }

 public void paint(Graphics g)
 { int counter=0;

 if(txtUser.getText().equals("Username") && txtPassword.getText().equals("Password"))
     g.drawString("Please enter your username and password ", 50, 100);



  if(blnCorrect)
   g.drawString("Successfully Logged in.", 50, 100);

  else

       while(txtUser.getText().equals("demo") && !txtPassword.getText().equals("demopassword")){
          counter=counter++;
          System.out.println(counter);
          txtUser.setText(" ");
          txtPassword.setText(" ");
          g.drawString("The password you introduced it's incorrect. ", 50, 100); 

          if(counter==3){ g.drawString("Log in blocked.", 50, 100);
          System.exit(12);
          }
       }




  if(!txtUser.getText().equals("demo"))
    g.drawString("Invalid username. ", 50, 90);
  }


 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`a = counter++;` does the following:

- Save the current value of `counter`.
- Add one to `counter`.
- Set `a` to the saved value.

Therefore, `counter = counter++;` does the following:

- Save the current value of `counter`.
- Add one to `counter`.
- Set `counter` to the saved value.

so it adds one, but then it immediately undoes it!

`counter = counter++;` is not what you want. Just use `counter++;` or `counter = counter+1;`

Comment: Thanks,but unfortunately I tried it that way and I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) for logging. It can log to file and stdout.
Also your counter works weird because of this:
    counter=counter++;
variable++ increments herself. 
You don't need to assignment result into variable. Simply use:
    counter++;